# Do friends get notified if I visit their villages?

Tags: clash-of-clans

If I visit some Facebook friend village in clash of clans, do they get notified in any way on game, notification bar or Facebook notification?

Comment: Nope. There are no features like this in the game. Can I inquire as to the reason for this question?

Answer (score 3):

No. CoC is not really FB oriented.